# Как запустить локально устновленный npm пакет? (Если официальная инструкция рекомендует установку глобально)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

В проекте используется пакет для деплоя по SFTP - https://github.com/lucasmotta/dploy

По докам для работы его нужно установить глобально

```
npm i dploy -g
```

Есть ли способ запустить его установив локально в проекте? Например через npm scripts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Установите пакет в ваш проект: `npm i dploy --save-dev`
2. Запустите его из вашей локальной папки `node_modules`: `./node_modules/.bin/dploy`

Вместо обращения к глобальному алиасу как в примере `dploy --version` Вам нужно будет обращаться к локально установленной `./node_modules/.bin/dploy --version`.

---

Для аналогичных случаев я добавляю такой путь в `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "scripts": {
    "dploy": "./node_modules/.bin/dploy"
  }
  ...
}
```

И использую как `npm run dploy --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым :)

Установить локально и добавить команду в скриптс

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "dploy"
  }
  ...
}
```